# Is it possible to accurately measure the turnout of Iranian elections?

Tags: iran

I do not think that the official election participation numbers published by the Iranian government is trustworthy.

Is it possible to measure the true number of Iranian people who vote in elections and are there any international monitoring on the elections?

Comment: I do not think, I think,... is not sufficient. facts needed.

Comment: There used to be a sport consisting in guessing actual statistics from the soviet union based on the official ones. They could only lie to some extent regarding population and nativity, turnout at the elections, education, ... Some trends had to be followed, but minimized if not approved of.